# Font rendering with CSS transform on Firefox in Windows 7 & 8 looks terribly grainy, jagged

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts, rendering

[If you check, for instance, this shopping page](https://slim.nl/Shop/browse/software/microsoft-office-professional-plus-2016?id=off16w), you can see that the prices are tilted by a few degrees. On Chrome this looks "just right", on Firefox this looks terribly distorted (Firefox, most recent, on Win7, Win8 but not Win10).

#### Rendering Chrome (similar to IE11), Windows 7:

> [image]

#### Rendering Firefox, Windows 7:

> [image]

I found similar anti-aliasing issues with some straight fonts, especially on mobile devices, not sure if that is related. Here's a rendering comparison of [TrustedReviews.com](http://www.trustedreviews.com/samsung-960-pro-1tb-review), of a straight font also looking terrible (ragged) in Firefox (Chrome is left, Firefox right).

[image]

Font choice seems irrelecant, changing the font to something basic, like `Arial`, still renders badly when tilted.

Is this a rendering issue with Firefox or does a solution exist? If so, how can this be fixed?

#### To reproduce

```css
.product-price span {
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-7deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-7deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-7deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-7deg);
    transform: rotate(-7deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}

.product-price {
    bottom: -29px;
    height: 55px;
    width: 83px;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-family: 'Arial';
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="product-price">
      <span>€ 15,<small>00</small></span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: In this case try to use: text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; on your body tag.

Comment: @Cheesy, just tried it locally, I don't see it having any discernible effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to self-solve this issue, as the resolution may help someone else.

It turned out that if I opened the page `about:support` (link won't render for security reasons, you have to type it in yourself) in Firefox it showed an error in the *Direct2D* entry, which usually only shows either `true` (enabled) or `false` (disabled).

I was pointed at this by one of the many reports on [support.mozilla.org](http://support.mozilla.org) with regards to font rendering issues, in particular, [this thread on Firefox 45 failing to render fonts properly](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1115938) pointed me in the right direction.

After upgrading my graphics driver the error disappeared and with it the rendering issues of fonts. The tilted font looks now just like it should, as do many other fonts on other sites.